# How do I customize the look and feel(customizing HTML structure) of the out of the box RSS viewer web part in sharepoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, ootb

here i want to customise the RSS reviewer web part where i can apply HTML any structure in sharepoint 2013. same thing i have done with custom web part but i want to try the same for OOTB web part?can any one guide me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Customizing RSS viewer webpart
[check this link might help](https://zioed.wordpress.com/2012/02/24/customizing-the-sharepoint-2010-rss-viewer-web-part-part-1-of-a-two-part-post-2/)